# I launched my app using IOS 6.1, will that lock me out of potential customers?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk

I would just like to ask a quick question. I have recently launched my app requiring IOS 6.1, It was the latest setting and I thought it will make my game more compatible with Iphone 5. However, as my game was approved and is now up for sale in itunes, i notice that I'm practically the only one (or one of a few) that requires IOS 6.1.

Most of the major players especially only require IOS 4.3 or IOS 5.0. That makes their games applicable even to non-IOS 6.1 phones. Does this mean that if a potential buyer hasn't yet updated his phone to IOS 6.1 he will not be able to use my app?

Did I just make a HUGE marketing mistake? Should I have launched my app with a much lower IOS minimum requirement?

How about you guys. Do you make your apps using the latest IOS SDK or make them using lower SDKs to appeal to a greater market?

Thanks for those who can give an insight.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's answer would most likely be that you *are* doing it the right way. You should always target the latest version of iOS first and foremost. Otherwise you risk developing your application for the lowest common denominator, i.e. without use of the latest API like collectionviews or autolayout, which may slow you down or prevent you from creating as nice of an experience for the user. If you can add support for earlier versions, great, but no one will fault you for only targeting 6.1. Along with doing it the right way first, the adoption rates are extremely high for iOS 6, so you are only missing out on a tiny fraction of the user base, as compared to supporting legacy OS versions in Android development.

[Apple chart of which iOS 6 features will work on which devices](http://b-i.forbesimg.com/tonybradley/files/2013/06/Screen-Shot-2013-06-21-at-2.51.29-PM.png)

To test support for older OS versions, try installing the iOS 6.0 simulator, dropping your development target to 6.0 (select your root project in the file navigator -> select your project -> Info tab), switching to the iOS 6.0 simulator and running your project.

Answer (score 2):

I would forget about any versions < 6.0 now, and especially < iOS 5.

The market share of devices running iOS 6 is large enough, and if you still program for devices lower than iOS5 you have to go to great lengths to implement some things that are really simple in iOS5 and higher (like customizing certain UI elements, sharing with social networks, ...), and you can't make use of auto layout etc.

That said, in your case I would require iOS 6.0 or higher, as the changes of the minor iOS updates normally are not that shocking to have a big influence on your code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. If you refer to some statistics, you'll find that the share of versions prior to 6.0 is almost negligible. You can find some of the numbers here: http://www.14oranges.com/2013/06/ios-version-statistics-june-14th-2013/

Comment: Those are comforting numbers. Still, I have unnecessarily locked myself out of 18% of the market. Do you believe there is still a way to change the deployment target?

Answer (score 1):

Which version to support is always a really confusing choice. But that being said iOS users are known to update to the newest versions within the first few months of its launch. The [penetration percentage](http://www.game4mob.com/index.php/tech-articles/67-ios-5-penetration-percentage) is pretty high. So you're probably not in that big of a stink.

If your app does run on the lower versions however (or can run on them without a huge effort), it would be a better strategy to support lower versions as well just to appeal to a larger market.

Comment: Thanks. That is a bit consoling to know. I had the reverse psychology in that I thought that an app using 6.1 can support the lower IOSs and that an app using 4.3 cannot support anything higher than it. I misunderstood that completely.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you made a mistake from what you have said. If your app doesn't NEED 6.1 then use the oldest iOS version you can, like 4.3.

As an example, when iOS 7 comes out, if you made your app requiring iOS 7, iPhone 3GS/3 users can't get it (just an example lol).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is there any way to fix this? Or not possible anymore? As a consolation, is it true what Apple claims that 94% of iPhone users now operate using IOS 6.0 or higher?

Comment: You mean change the deployment target ? And I don't know about that claim, it might be true but either way you are still losing customers by making it for 6.1 :)

Comment: Yes the deployment target. Is there any quick way to change that?

Comment: Can you not just open the project in xCode, then just change the deployment target in the drop down ?

Comment: Will I have to pull the plug on my app completely and re-submit it for review? Or will that kind of change be possible in a version update? Thanks.

Comment: Should be possible in a version update I think

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what user base you are targeting.

- **I go for the crowd.** You are not in any danger. Statistics show that the newest version of iOS becomes the most used in several weeks after the launch. iOS 6 is currently at around 97% according to Apple. I expect iOS 7 to come to the same state very fast too.
- **I have a very specific target audience.** You need to know your users. Are they geeks? Are they general users? What is the distribution of iOS versions among them? You can find the statistics for this.